# Audio Equalizer affecting FRAPS recording - Is there a way to create my own playback device?

Tags: audio, teamspeak, fraps, equalizer

Using Win7, A corsair vengeance 2000 headset and teamspeak.

For about 2 weeks now, FRAPS is being affected by the equalizer settings I entered in the Corsair software. This means that when I play back the footage the same equalizer will be modifying the audio again. I can't think of anything that I changed at around the right time.

Something else - I'm experimenting with MSI Afterburner after having used fraps for years. This software allows me to choose the playback device as seen in the windows control panel. Is there perhaps a way to create a virtual playback device that takes audio from multiple sources so I can record my local mic input along with the game sounds and teamspeak? Perhaps this would allow me to fix the equalizer being applied twice as well.